# How can I get Heroku to properly deploy an application from a sub-directory?

Tags: heroku

I'm having trouble deploying from my server sub-directory. I've been searching around all of Stack Overflow and none of the answers were able to help me fix this. I made use of `npm --prefix` as well as `git subtree push --prefix server heroku master`. I have listed below my file structure, package.json, and Heroku logs.

File Structure:

```
- client
- server
```

package.json snippet:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix ../client && npm run build --prefix ../client"
```

Heroku Logs:

```
remote: npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! syscall open
remote: npm ERR! path /tmp/client/package.json
remote: npm ERR! errno -2
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/client/package.json'
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote: npm ERR! enoent 
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.x8Dnr/_logs/2021-01-23T22_37_55_270Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 254
remote: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix ../client && npm run build --prefix ../client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 254
```

Comment: Did you mean `./client`?

Comment: Nope. Since I prefixed into server wouldn't it be inside server folder? And I would need to ../client to get out in order to reach my client directory

Comment: Well which package.json are you showing? Evidently you have at least two, probably three as you need one at the root for the buildpack.

Comment: The package.json I'm showing is in my server directory. Is it possible to not have it at the root? I'm really committed to this file structure and would prefer to deploy from the server directory

Comment: It seems you've *only* pushed the server directory to Heroku, the client code isn't there at all. That's how you've made the server's package file be at the root, which is a requirement. You could have a third package file at the root and push the whole repo, then both server and client files are available - you already know how to use prefix.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense to me now. I'm going to try this approach. I thought this whole time it was unable to find my client directory